# NestJS crypto: What is the purpose of the promisify(scrypt)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, cryptojs

I was going through [nestjs Encryption and Hashing documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/encryption-and-hashing) and it shows this:

```js
import { createCipheriv, randomBytes, scrypt } from 'crypto';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const iv = randomBytes(16);
const password = 'Password used to generate key';

// The key length is dependent on the algorithm.
// In this case for aes256, it is 32 bytes.
const key = (await promisify(scrypt)(password, 'salt', 32)) as Buffer;
const cipher = createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', key, iv);

const textToEncrypt = 'Nest';
const encryptedText = Buffer.concat([
  cipher.update(textToEncrypt),
  cipher.final(),
]);
```

I couldn't understand this line:

```js
const key = (await promisify(scrypt)(password, 'salt', 32)) as Buffer;
```

Here are my questions:

1. What is this line doing?
2. Why do i have to do this? In other tutorials they just use the key instead of doing this line.What does 'salt' means? On the method documentation I only found `arg2: BinaryLike`
3. What does 'salt' means? On the method documentation I only found `arg2: BinaryLike`

Comment: See [this post](https://brunoscopelliti.com/blog/new-util-promisify-in-nodejs/) discussing `util.promisify` in node, and the respected [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Answer (score 2):

### 1 What is this line doing?

[`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) is a utility that can take a node style callback function (a function that has the last argument as a function taking err and result such as `fs.readFile('fileToRead', (err, res) => { if (err) throw err; console.log(res); })`) and make it a promised method that can either be `.then`ned or `await`ed.  It helps make for cleaner code in the modern JS ecosystem.

So awith the above, instead of needing to

```js
scrypt(password, salt, 32, (err, result) => doSomethingWithTheResutlAndError(err, result))
```

you can just do

```js
const result = await scrypt(password, salt, 32)
```

### 2 Why do i have to do this? / 3 What does `salt` means?

I'm not sure what you mean about `arg2: BinaryLike`. [This is the documentation from Node's site](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback).

As found by OP in the comments, the `scrypt` method is necessary because it transforms the key into the proper 32-bit Buffer format for the `createCipheriv` method.

In general, a [`salt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) is an extra (usually random) string that gets added when creating a hash so that when you hash a string multiple times it comes out to different values. This helps provide safety in the case of a database leak, because no two passwords will look alike, even if they happen to be `password123` every time.

To know what you mean about "other tutorials" you'd have to show what they're doing specifically.

---

For hashing, I personally use [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) or [argon2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argon2), but the `scrypt` method from Node's `crypto` module is another good choice.

Comment: What i mean by other tutorials is that this line doesnt even exist, when they call the method `createCipheriv` they send the password directly ([Example](https://attacomsian.com/blog/nodejs-encrypt-decrypt-data#:~:text=and%20decrypt%20streams-,Node.,%2C%20sign%2C%20and%20verify%20functions.))

Comment: But that article isn't using `scrypt`. It's using `createCipheriv` which is a different method all together

Comment: the only use for the variable declared using the `scrypt` on the nestjs tutorial (see code on question) is for the password used on `createCipheriv`

Comment: So in Nest's docs it's showing the creation of a hashed key that will be used for the cipher (extra security). You can honestly ignore it if you really want, and just use a single string for the key.  [Here's the docs for createCipheriv](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options)

Comment: I see... Going to do that then. Do you know why nestjs is doing that on the docs?

Comment: Like I said, extra security. Using a random (but saved) key instead of the same one each time leads to the possibility of having fewer leaks due to having different keys for the ciphers

Comment: Hey, just found out why. That line transforms the password in the format expected by the algorithm. since im using aes-256-ctr it transforms the password in a 32bit Buffer. Without doing so it throws an error because the password is in an wrong format. Probably worth adding in the answer since i accepted it and thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
crypto.scrypt(password, salt, keylen[, options], callback)
```

[`crypto.scrypt`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scrypt_password_salt_keylen_options_callback) is a function that takes an ["error-first" callback function](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_first_callbacks): `scrypt` will *asynchronously* derive a key and call the callback method to return a value, passing the callback the two parameters `err` and `data` (here the `data` is a Buffer documented as `derivedKey`).

[`util.promisfy`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) is a utility that takes a Function and returns a Function: You pass it a Function that uses error-first callbacks, and it returns a Function that returns a Promise instead of passing back a callback method. This allows you to use `await`, as in your sample code, as well as `then`-chaining and tools like `Promise.all`.

```js
const key = (await promisify(scrypt)(password, 'salt', 32)) as Buffer;
//            This ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is just a function based on scrypt.
```

[Salt](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/what-is-a-cryptographic-salt) is a common term for a random cryptographic value stored per-record; for `scrypt` in particular the salt "should be as unique as possible", recommending that "a salt is random and at least 16 bytes long". Further information is available on [crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1776) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

Answer (score 1):

Beacause crypto.scrypt() is async, but not support promise coding style.
Infact:

```
    const key = (await promisify(scrypt)(password, 'salt', 32)) as Buffer;
```

is equal to:

```
    function scryptPromisify(password, salt, keylen, options) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.scrypt(password, salt, keylen, options, (err, derivedKey) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(derivedKey);
          }
        });
      });
    }
    const key = await scryptPromise(password, 'salt', 32);
```